# Redirecting to Facebook page or Facebook app

Tags: php

I would like to redirect a facebook page to using facebook app if the user installed facebook app into his/her android or ios device.

For example below, the url would be "https://www.facebook.com/mashable". I'm only able to redirect the user to that page on his/her browser. However, I would like to force the user to open the link using the facebook app if it's installed in the device.

```
$sql_stmt = "SELECT landing_url FROM landingurl WHERE fb = 1 AND page = 'mashable' LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql );  

if($row):
    $landing_url = $row["landing_url"];
    header("Location: ".$landing_url); exit;
elseif:
    echo "No page found";
endif;
```